# React Native SVG Import Return Number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

Hello last 2 day I struggle with this SVG issue.
First problem is I cannot import svg file it says cannot find module then
I fix it about declaring  problem.
Then I find a solution by writing svg data in func like that:

```js
const notifactionIcon = (
  width = 60,
  height = 60
) => `<svg width="${width}" height="${height}" viewBox="0 0 60 60" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <rect width="60" height="60" fill="url(#pattern0)" />
    <defs>
        <pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
            <use xlink:href="#image0_18_78" transform="scale(0.01)" />
        </pattern>
        <image id="image0_18_78" width="100" height="100"
            xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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" />
    </defs>
</svg>`

export { notifactionIcon }
```

But I want to import manually.

[image]
It's pretty interesting
[image]

I search on internet. I cannot find any solution with this problem

Did anyone know why this happening?

other things

babel

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true)
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
  }
}
```

tsconfig

```
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
  }
}
```

webpack

```
import createExpoWebpackConfigAsync from "@expo/webpack-config/webpack"
import { Arguments, Environment } from "@expo/webpack-config/webpack/types"

module.exports = async function (env: Environment, argv: Arguments) {
  const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync(env, argv)

  return config
}
```

package

```
{
  "name": "cookingapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "lint": "eslint '**/* .{js,ts,tsx,jsx}'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^0.17.2",
    "babel-plugin-inline-import": "^3.0.0",
    "expo": "^46.0.10",
    "expo-cli": "^6.0.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "firebase": "9.6.11",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "idb": "^7.0.2",
    "node-fs": "^0.1.7",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "^0.70.1",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.4",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.13.2",
    "react-native-svg-uri": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.1.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.14",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.69.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.37.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.37.0",
    "eslint": "^8.23.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-node": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.8",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Thanks for answer from now...

Comment: check this: [Adding svgs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/#adding-svgs)

Comment: do you find a solution? I'm struggling with the same problem, when I build the library, all imports fails from another project

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the `SvgXml` component to render the SVG file.
Looking at their [usage docs](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg/blob/main/USAGE.md), you need to update your babel config file.

1. Update the babel file with the `module:metro-react-native-babel-preset` preset and the `babel-plugin-inline-import` plugin.

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true)
  return {
    presets: [
      "babel-preset-expo",
      "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"
    ],
    plugins: [
    [
      "babel-plugin-inline-import",
      {
        "extensions": [".svg"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

2. Import the SVG file and use the SvgXml Component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { SvgXml } from 'react-native-svg';
import testSvg from './test.svg';

export default () => <SvgXml width="200" height="200" xml={testSvg} />;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can render your SVGs using **XML strings** instead of importing it  :

**1-** import :  `import { SvgXml } from 'react-native-svg';`

**2-**  go inside your **SVG file**, you’ll notice a bunch of XML code with an `<svg>` tag copy everything inside that `<svg>` element from the SVG file’s XML code and store it inside a variable. like this

```
const icon = <svg ....>...</svg>
```

**3-** Then, pass the icon  variable to the *xml prop* inside your `<SvgXml>` component, like this :

```
<SvgXml xml={icon} width="100%" height="100%" />
```